# How match data inside a tag, but don't other similar tags

Tags: regex, html

Regexr link for the lazy: http://regexr.com?33udv

Test string:

```
<li><a href="#"><strong>Start</strong></a></li><li><a href="#">End</a></li>
```

I want to match when I search for "Start"

```
<li><a href="#"><strong>Start</strong></a></li>
```

My pattern is this:

```
<li>(?!<li>)*Start.*?</li>
```

My issue is that it's matching both list children, when I only want to match the one that contains "Start".

*Note: This is a very predictable html string that will always look the same. I know Regex shouldn't parse html, but the question is more about understanding of Negative Lookaheads.*

Solution:

```
<li>((?!<li>).)*Start.*?</li>
```

Comment: You are still mentioning negative lookaheads in your question...

Comment: I think you are right, how would I utitlize negative lookahead?
`<li>(?!<li>)*End.*?</li>`

Comment: You don't need negative lookaheads in this case and they wouldn't be helpful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The expression you posted is different than the one from the link. I will focus on the one from the link.*

`.*` is greedy, it will try to find the longest match. You want it to be [**lazy**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
<li>.*?Start.*?</li>
```